# Simple array, uncertainty with output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I'm studying for my Java Exam in a few days. In my practice packet, I had the following code. My prediction of the output was 4 1 ... which wasn't even a choice. The answer was 1 1 2 3 4 5. But I don't understand how it got to this output. My guess is I'm getting thrown off around the 5th line(myList[i...). If anyone has the patience to break it down for me I'd appreciate it. I don't want answers for my work here, I just wanna understand them.

public class Test10 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myList = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    for (int i = myList.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        myList[i + 1] = myList[i];
    }

    for (int e: myList)
        System.out.print(e + " ");

}
```

}

Comment: add prints in your first loop to help trace the code .... or trace it by hand.

Comment: The last items index would be `.length - 1`. The loop starts placing in the last item the value of prior item, and then goes back to finally i == 0, filling the item at index 1 with the first item at 0.

Comment: The values of `i` will be 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. When `i` is 4, `myList[i + 1] = myList[i]` will store `myList[4]` (which is 5) at index 5 (remember that arrays in Java are zero-based, so 0 is the first index and 5 is the last index). The array will then be `{1,2,3,4,5,5}`. Carry on...

Comment: public class Test10 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  int[] myList = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  
  for (int i = myList.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) { // so far I believe "i" is at 3 because the length(6) -2 = 4 => is currently > 0 then subtracted by 1.
   myList[i + 1] = myList[i]; // so now I believe its trying to add that 3 with the 1. being the new "i"
  }
  
  for (int e: myList)
   System.out.print(e + " ");
  
 }

}

Comment: A for-loop of the form `for (init; cond; incr) { body }` is executed as follows: 1. Execute `init`. 2. Evaluate `cond`, if it's false exit the loop. 3. Execute `body`. 4. Execute `incr`. 5. Go to step 2. Note that the body is executed *before* the first time `incr` is executed.